# Creating HTML table content based on database information as columns and row headings overlap

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to be able to create a table systematically based on information form a database. I am able to create the columns and row titles/headings systematically. I am struggling to get the table content correct.

In this case I have a scenario where there are three samples each with selected analyses results that have to be entered in the table. Some of the analyses overlaps with the different samples and others do not. Each analysis corresponds to a number. So analysis 1 = 1 and analysis 2 = 2 and analysis 3 =3. Each sample has its own analyses and displayed as an array: `Sample1 ([0] => 1) sample2 ([0] => 2 [1] => 3)` and `sample3 ([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)`. The analyses arrays are combined and duplicates removed to produce column names:

```
column headings: ([0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)
```

I need the table inputs only to be available to samples that has that particular analysis. My question is how can I have the database information be filtered to produce the relevant column input information? I marked the section in the code of my attempt to produce the relevant input, however it does not produce a result.

```
   <?php 
    if (!isset($_GET['display_results'])) {
      require '../server/dbh.php';
      header("Location: ../web_page/analysis_results_disp_page.php?display_results=error");
    } else {
      $order_id = $_GET['display_results'];
      $query = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis<>'';";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      $query2 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE order_id=$order_id AND micro_analysis<>'';";
      $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

      $micro_analysis = '';
      while($input = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $micro_analysis .= $input['micro_analysis'] . ',';
      }
      $micro_analysis_arr = array_filter(array_unique(explode(',', $micro_analysis)));

      ?>
      <form action="#" method="POST">
       <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th colspan="1"></th> 
           <?php
           foreach ($micro_analysis_arr as $row) {
            $query3 = "SELECT * FROM microbiology_analysis_database WHERE id=$row"; 
            $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $query3);
            $input2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
            $analysis = $input2['m_analysis'];
            ?> 
            <th colspan="2"><?php echo $analysis; ?></th>
          <?php } ?>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <?php
       if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
          $sample_id = $row['sample_id']; ?> 
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['env_sam_id']; ?></td>
            <?php
//This is the start of the section in question:
            foreach ($micro_analysis_arr as $row) { 
              $query4 = "SELECT * FROM samples_database WHERE sample_id=$sample_id AND m_analysis=$row"; 
              $result4 = mysqli_query($conn, $query4);
              $resultCheck4 = mysqli_num_rows($result4);

              if ($resultCheck4 > 0) { ?>

               <td><select name="<?php echo $row; ?>">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
                <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
              </select></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>

            <?php } else { ?>

             <td></td>
             <td></td>

           <?php } } ?>
         </tr>
       <?php } } ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>      
    <?php   
    } 
    ?>
```

EDIT!

Here is an example of what the table should look like instead of all the input in each column:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="1"></th> 
      <th colspan="2">Analysis 1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Analysis 2</th>
      <th colspan="2">Analysis 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample 1</td>
      <td><select name="">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
      </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <td>Sample 2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><select name="">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
    <td><select name="">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
    </select></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
  </tr>
  <td>Sample 3</td>
  <td><select name="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
  <td><select name="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
  <td><select name="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Detected?</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="ND">Not Determined</option>
  </select></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="#" placeholder="Enter Result"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what the data would look like when inserted into the database:

```
INSERT INTO `samples_database` (`sample_id`, `order_id`, `env_sam_id`, `micro_analysis`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'sample 1', '1'), ('2', '1', 'sample 2', '2,3'), ('3', '1', 'sample 3', '1,2,3')
```

And the analysis database information:

```
INSERT INTO `microbiology_analysis_database` (`id`, `m_analysis`) VALUES ('1', 'analysis1'), ('2', 'analysis2'), ('3', 'analysis3')
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your comment, however this code I have removed from this simplified version just for the sake of my question.

Comment: Ok. Anyway, regarding your question, it would be a lot simpler to understand if we could see a sample of the database data, and your expected output.

Comment: @ADyson Yes for sure! In what format, I am not sure how I would present database information.

Comment: Just as a simple table, it can be formatted like your code. Even a screenshot of the table(s) is better than nothing, although harder for us to use to make a demo or anything